# Why variable is not overwritten with new value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a simple console application which does mathematical functions,.

My problem is that inside `MakeFirstStageCalculations`'s `while` loop, the remainder is not overwritten with new remainder, what am I missing here?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Generator A starting value: ");//put 65
    string generatorAValue = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(MakeFirstStageCalculations(Convert.ToDecimal(generatorAValue), 16807));
}

public static int MakeFirstStageCalculations(decimal value, decimal coefficient, decimal division = 2147483647)
{

    decimal multiplicationValue = value * coefficient;
    decimal remainder = MakeRemainder(multiplicationValue, division); //first remainder starting value if value is 65 i posted what values should be returned. 
    int donein = 0; // how long while loop needed to complete.
    #if DEBUG
    int goodvalue = 0;
    #endif
    while (remainder != 0)
    {
        remainder = MakeRemainder(remainder, division);//PROBLEM IS RIGHT HERE,it should return new remained and overwrite.
        Console.WriteLine(remainder);

        #if DEBUG
        if (goodvalue == 10)
        {
            break;
        }
        goodvalue++;
        #endif
        donein++;
    }
    /*First 4 remainder values should be:
     * 1092455
     * 1181022009
     * 245556042
     * 1744312007
     */
    return donein;
}

private static decimal MakeRemainder(decimal multiplicationValue, decimal division)
{
    decimal z = multiplicationValue / division;
            z = multiplicationValue - z;
            return z;
}
```

I'm willing to elaborate more in the comments if the current explanation is not sufficient.

First 4 numbers which are CORRECT are:

1092455

1181022009

245556042

1744312007

According to task, formula is:

1. User input value(65) is multiplied from coefficient(16807);
2. Multiplied result is divided from(2147483647);
3. Result is remnant of division;
4. That result BECOME the initial number of the next iteration.

Did I made wrong formula?

Comment: I imagine it should be division % multiplication.

Comment: int32 or any int type?

Comment: @speed258 `65*16807=1092455`. That divided by a larger number (like `2147483647`) to get the remainder will still be `1092455`. So unless you make the division smaller you will always get the same remainder. What are you trying to do? What other result do you expect to get with the input `65`? Show the mathematics of your calculation with the input `65`.

Comment: 1092455 / 2147483647 = 5.087140018626647e-4 = basically 0. Due to floating point rounding errors the remainder is always going to be 1092455. I tried using double instead of int to no success. You're going to need to use a third party math library that can handle really large and really small numbers.

Comment: @Progman simplified idea should be: 
result = (65*16807) / 2147483647;
newresult = result / 2147483647 ;
newresult2 = newresult / 2147483647 ; If I change to double all int then I get incorrect answer, but at least values are changing(does not work).

Comment: @speed258 The operators `/` and `%` are different. Also, you are using integer division, so the result will always be rounded to the number zero. Please [edit] your question to include the mathematical steps you do with the input `65`. Include the steps in single lines to show what values you want to calculate.

Comment: @Progman added simplified maths on how everything should go.

Comment: @speed258 `1092455 % 2147483647` will still be `1092455`. Why do you think the result will be `1181022009`?

Comment: if I put 1092455 as starting value I get second correct value, @Progman but in this case looks like int is not correct format for me, should I go with float/double?

Comment: @speed258 Well, that's not what you wrote. You have neither said nor written in your code that you replace `value` with a different value. In your code and explanation it is still `65` (and not changed). Please rewrite your mathematical steps on what you want to calculate instead and a detailed description of your problem.

Comment: 1092455 is smaller than 2147483647 so the remainder of 1092455 % 2147483647 will always be 1092455.

Comment: Oh. I think I got it to work. Use decimal instead of int. Then replace var z = multiplicationValue % division; with var z = multiplicationValue / division; z = multiplicationValue - z;

Comment: @Progman " remainder = MakeRemainder(remainder, division);//PROBLEM IS RIGHT HERE,it should return new remained and overwrite." copy and CTRL+F this code and you will find where i have problem.

Comment: @speed258 The result of `1092455 % 2147483647` is `1092455`. But how do you get from `1092455` to your desired value `1181022009`? It is unclear what calculation you want to perform. Please [edit] the listed mathematical steps on how you get from the value in `result` to `newresult`.

Comment: @speed258 The expected values in your post are wrong.  (65*16807) % 2147483647 = 1092454.99949. Then 1092454.99949 % 2147483647 = 1092454.99898. Then 1092454.99898 % 2147483647 = 1092454.99898. Use my fix and your get this values.

Comment: @SkyeMacMaster I still getting same: 1092454,9989825719965115590013, Progman I updated my post to show how exact formula should look like on each while go.

Comment: I think the down votes are unnecessary.  Please reconsider.

Comment: @speed258 That number is the correct first result. As I said, the expected values you listed are wrong. If you divide a number by a much larger you will get a small fractional number. Resulting in a remainder slightly less then the starting number, The remainder could never be larger then the original number.

Comment: @speed258 Your math formulas are still wrong, they do not calculate what you think they do. The result of `((65*16807) % 2147483647)% 2147483647` is `1092455`, which is the same as `(65*16807) % 2147483647` and `((((65*16807) % 2147483647)% 2147483647)% 2147483647)% 2147483647`. There is no difference on how often you calculate the remainder of the same value with the same divisor. Please [edit] your question to fix the calculation of your math formulas and show what value you want to calculate. Specially explain or show how you get from the value `1092455` to the new value `1181022009`.

Comment: @Progman I added task with formula which tells how these numbers need to be retrieved. And provided numbers ARE correct. I believe my formula is not quite right.

Comment: What does it mean to be divided **from** a value? If you divide a **by** b, you do `a/b`, if you divide a **from** b, do you do `b/a`? Is that what that means? If so, then I think you got the division operands in the wrong order in your function.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen look for my post end formula according to task how it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you don't use the calculated remainder as the new start value for the next iteration. The start value is save in the variable `value` and the variable `multiplicationValue` is only calculated once. After that you are calculating the remainder which will be the same for each iteration. What you are calculating is something like

```
42 % 100 = 42
```

which is the same as

```
((((42 % 100) % 100) % 100) % 100) = 42
```

since you can replace `42 % 100` with just `42` every time.

You need to trigger the initial multiplication again with the new remainder calculated. The code should look like this:

```
int startValue = 65;
int coefficient = 16807;
int divisor = 2147483647;

int iterationValue = startValue; // (2)
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    long multipliedValue = (long)iterationValue * (long)coefficient;
    int remainder = (int)(multipliedValue % divisor);
    Console.WriteLine(i+": "+remainder);
    iterationValue = remainder;  // (1)
}
```

*(the `for` loop is only for testing, use your `while` loop in your code instead)*

The variable `iterationValue` will contain the new iteration value with the calculated remainder at the end at the loop (marked with `(1)`) and it will initialized with the original start value (marked with `(2)`, in this case it's `65`). When you run this code you will get the following output:

```
0: 1092455
1: 1181022009
2: 245556042
3: 1744312007
4: 1352636452
5: 498961622
6: 124339419
7: 271026602
8: 331284527
9: 1621432265
```

As you see you will find your first four wanted values at the top.

The second problem is that you use/[used](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58190530/4) only the type `int` for your calculations. This can result in problems. After the first iteration you are about to calculate the multiplication value `1092455 * 16807`, which is `18360891185`. However, this value does not fit into an `int32` variable. You get a so called "integer overflow", which will result in a negative value. With only integer types/values you will get the following output instead:

```
0: 1092455
1: 1181022001
2: -1902071305
3: -670839007
4: -502038649
5: 1847162897
6: 1243194391
7: -647765503
8: 747286439
9: 1158806769
```

With changing the values/types to `long` at the right places you can do the multiplication and remainder calculation without getting negative values. You might want to consider using [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8) values to avoid this problem as well.